# RADIUS use outside of network AAA

Tags: authentication, radius

I've seen RADIUS used for wireless authentication, but are there any other use cases that RADIUS works well in?

Has anyone had experience with using RADIUS for AAA between two applications? I'm assuming this is possible, but wanted to to see if anyone's had prior experience.

Comment: There are tons of resources explaining this. Have you performed any research on the topic? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS

Answer (score 1):

I have used RADIUS to authenticate VPN users (both **OpenVPN** and  **Cisco** in two different set-ups) and it worked very well. There is a few of other uses for RADIUS incuding authenticating WPA2 users, Ethernet clients (generally 802.1x).